# Emphasise text when gls{} is used

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, emphasis

I'm currently writing my master thesis. I will handout a PDF version and a printed version aswell.

For the reason that hyperlinks will not look very good in the printed version I will remove them with the draft option for hyperlinks. This will unfortunately lead to the problem that all my abbreviations and glossary entries (all made with `\gls`) within the text will not stand out anymore. I'm wondering if there is an option to emphasise the text which is used within `\gls{}` without using `\emph{\gls{}}`, so that the reader know that these words are explained somewhere else. The last option would mean a lot of manual work to change all entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=super,toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossarystyle{clong}{
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}{p{.3\linewidth}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
        & \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4\glspostdescription\space ##6\\}%
% Groupskip verhindert den leeren Platz nach anderen Buchstaben
%   \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
}

\newglossaryentry{ATL-g}{name= {ATL},
    description={Sich wiederholende Tätigkeiten, welche die psychischen und physischen menschlichen Grundbedürfnisse erfüllen}}
\newglossaryentry{ATL}{type=\acronymtype, name={ATL}, description={Aktivitäten des täglichen Leben}, first={Aktivitäten des täglichen Lebens (ATL)\glsadd{ATL-g}}, see=[Glossar]{ATL-g}}

\newacronym{ANN}{ANN}{Artificial Neuronal Network}
\begin{document}
\printglossary[style = clong, type=\acronymtype]
\newpage
\printglossary[style = clong, type=main]
\newpage

\gls{ATL} glossary test with \gls{ANN}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (MWE) of your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

If you use `glossaries-extra` you can change the textformat for different entry types:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=super,toc,acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{textformat}{emph}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{textformat}{emph}

\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossnamefont}{emph}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossnamefont}{emph}


\makeglossaries
\newglossarystyle{clong}{
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}{p{.3\linewidth}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
        & \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4\glspostdescription\space ##6\\}%
% Groupskip verhindert den leeren Platz nach anderen Buchstaben
%   \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
}

\newglossaryentry{ATL-g}{name= {ATL},
    description={Sich wiederholende Tätigkeiten, welche die psychischen und physischen menschlichen Grundbedürfnisse erfüllen}}
\newglossaryentry{ATL}{type=\acronymtype, name={ATL}, description={Aktivitäten des täglichen Leben}, first={Aktivitäten des täglichen Lebens (ATL)\glsadd{ATL-g}}, see=[Glossar]{ATL-g}}

\newacronym{ANN}{ANN}{Artificial Neuronal Network}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[style = clong, type=\acronymtype]
\newpage
\printglossary[style = clong, type=main]
\newpage

\gls{ATL} glossary test with \gls{ANN}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can change the entry format by redefining `\glsentryfmt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \emph{\glslabel}%
}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry{utc}{name=UTC, description={Coordinated Universal Time}}
\newglossaryentry{adt}{name=ADT, description={Atlantic Daylight Time}}
\newglossaryentry{est}{name=EST, description={Eastern Standard Time}}

\gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt} and 10 hours ahead of \gls{est}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not seem do work for me. I added some MWE perhaps I need to adapt your solution to my code?

Comment: Made an attempt on your MWE